# Why does my try statement keep repeating itself?

Tags: python

I know there are other issues with this code but I am wondering why the try statement stays stuck in the loop. I put a break statement after I return the salesPrice I also tried putting the break before I returned the salesPrice and it does not work. Why isnt it breaking out of the loop with the break statement?

```
def getFloatInput(sales):
    i = True
    while i:
        try:
            salesPrice = getFloatInput(float(input("Enter property sales value: ")))
            return salesPrice
            break
            if salesPrice <= 0:
                print("Enter a numeric value greater than 0")
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a numeric value")
        continue

def main():
    sales = float(input("Enter property sales value: "))
    addToList = []
    i = True
    while i:
        addToList.append(getFloatInput(sales))
        repeat = input("Enter another value Y or N: ")
        if repeat == "Y":
            getFloatInput(sales)
        else:
            break

main()
```

Comment: You make the function call itself without any condition, so that is an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the issues:

- The function `getFloatInput` calls itself over and over again, without any condition. There is no reason for it to call itself, since you already have a loop that allows for repeating the prompt.
- The code that follows immediately below the `return` statement can never be reached
- The `sales` argument is never used by `getFloatInput`. It is an unnecessary parameter.
- The main code will call `getFloatInput` a second time in the `if` block, but that value is then ignored -- it is not added to the list. `getFloatInput` should not be called there. The loop should just make its next iteration where it will be called.
- The `i` name is overkill. You can just do `while True:`.
- `continue` at the end of a loop body has no use -- the loop will anyhow continue when execution gets at that point.

Here is a corrected version:

```
def getFloatInput():
    while True:
        try:
            salesPrice = float(input("Enter property sales value: "))
            if salesPrice > 0:
                return salesPrice
            print("Enter a numeric value greater than 0")
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a numeric value")

def main():
    addToList = []
    while True:
        addToList.append(getFloatInput())
        repeat = input("Enter another value Y or N: ")
        if repeat != "Y":
            break

main()
```

Comment: Omg you are my knight in shining armor. Thank you so much. I am new to python and I do not understand completely how functions work. The way you explained it really helps me I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days on my own. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your `getFloatInput(sales)` function within the function itself, on the line `salesPrice = getFloatInput(float(input("Enter a property sales values: ")))`. Your code isn't actually reaching your `return salesPrice` line because you are calling the function again.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for days! It is so frustrating. I am confused because when I try to call the getFloatInput with a argument in it, it does not work. I know it is becaise it is out out of scope. I am trying to ask that input question everytime I call the getFloatInput but nothing works I try getFloatInput(salesPrice) and it will say name not defined. I do not understand it.